# Python3 RE issue with '\n'

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I'm trying to do a simple regular expression in Python3 that just provides me the Twitter id.

Why does the following not work?

```
import re
s="twitter.com/atechnofou\\nInstagram:"
all_matches = re.findall("twitter\.com/[^?\\\"\'>&\*\n\r\ <]+", s)
```

It returns:
['twitter.com/atechnofou\nInstagram:']

But I'd like it to return
['twitter.com/atechnofou']

---

If I change my re.findall to this, it works, but why?

```
all_matches = re.findall("twitter\.com/[^?\"\'>&\*\n\r\\\ <]+", s)
```

All I've done is moved the \\ from the beginning of the [] block to closer to the end.

Comment: `\\n` is two characters: a literal backslash and the letter n, not a new line.

Comment: But shouldn't the \\ still catch it?

Comment: Yes, I posted that above.

Comment: Why doesn't the first RE expression work?

Comment: The first one does work, with a **raw** string.  Note the leading `r` before the string: `all_matches = re.findall(r"twitter\.com/[^?\\\"\'>&\*\n\r\ <]+", s)`.  Sorry, I didn't paste the right one in the previous now deleted comment.  A raw string doesn't translate escape codes like \\ and \n and passes them to the `re` engine.  The double translation is what is breaking your first string.